# how do i make an IF statement on xcode that makes a UIButton work?

Tags: if-statement, authentication, uibutton

i want to make an IF/Else statement that will grant a user access only if he has input the right code - for example, a log in - if he were to put in John Smith in the username text box, he would be able to press the Log in button, otherwise, it would not work.

this is the code i have

```
    if ([usernameText.text is EqualToString:@"jzarate"]) {

(insert code that grants functionality to the "log in button")

else ([insert code that does not grant functionality to the "log in button"])
```

i also want to do the same with a password that is made up of digits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
if ([usernameText.text is EqualToString:@"jzarate"]) 
{
    yourButton.enabled = YES;
}    
else 
{
    yourButton.enabled = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is `-(void)setUserInteractionEnabled:(BOOL)enabled`.

What you want to do is add a target to your textField's editingDidEnd like this:

```
[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(editEnded:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];
```

Then, you want to set the button to enabled by implementing the editEnded method, such as:

```
-(void)editEnded:(UITextField *)textField {
    if ([textField.text isEqualToString:@"jzarate"]) {
        [button setEnabled:YES];
    }
    else {
        [button setEnabled:NO];
    }
 }
```

You just have to make sure you have a reference to the button that you can access from inside of the editEnded method in order to do this.

You can also implement `UIControlEventEditingDidBegin` or `UIControlEventEditingDidChange` if you want to set the button to enabled when editing begins or whenever the value in the textField is changed.